# Pushing into array mongoose and mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I get the following error `Cannot create field 'likes' in element` whenever I am trying to push into my `likeList` array nested inside my comments.

When executing the following:

```
   Feed.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            owner: req.body.authorId,
            "posts.comments.commentList._id": req.body.commentId
          },
          {
            $push: {
              "posts.$.comments.commentList.likes.likeList": {
                user: req.user._id,
                avatar: req.user.profile.profile_picture.url,
                name: req.user.name
              }
        )
```

And my schema is as follows:

**Feed Schema**

```
 owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "userType"
  },
         posts: [
            {
               author: {
               userType: {
               type: String,
               enum: ["IndustryPartner", "User", "School"]
            },
            user: {
              type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
              ref: "posts.author.userType", //<- This may cause an issue, if there are any issues with retrieving user fields, CHECK THIS
              required: true
            },
            name: { type: String, required: true },
            avatar: { type: String, required: true }
          },
              comments: {
                totalComments: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                commentList: [
                  {
                    likes: {
                      totalLikes: { type: Number, default: 0 },
                      likeList: [ <---//Trying to push here
                        {
                          user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
                          avatar: { type: String },
                          name: { type: String },
                          date: {
                            type: Date,
                            default: Date.now
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    ...
```

I am not sure if it's an issue with the query I am using in the first parameter to filter.

**Update entire error message**
It is odd because it appears that it is actually finding the correct commentList to go to, but is unable to access the likes field within the array itself. Am I wrong assuming that this should be able to step through it? `posts.$.comments.commentList.likes.likeList`

```
      { MongoError: Cannot create field 'likes' in element {commentList: [ { likes: { totalLikes: 0, likeList: [] }, 
_id: ObjectId('5cf6b3293b61fe06f48794e3'), user: ObjectId('5c9bf6eb1da18b038ca660b8'), avatar: "https://sli.blob.core.windows.net/stuli/
profile-picture-e1367a7a-41c2-4ab4-9cb5-621d2008260f.jpg", name: "Luke Skywalker", text: "Test comment from Luke", repliesToComment: [], date: new Date(1559671593009) } ]}
```

Answer (score 0):

After further research, it appears the positional operator is no longer useful after stepping through 2 levels of arrays. So, the solution would be to use JS to change push the values into the array and then save them.